# Python Tkinter grids inside Classes

Tags: python, object, recursion, tkinter, grid

So I'm having this issue where I am trying to place a grid frame INSIDE another grid frame. I was able to pull it off in other programs. But for some reason, I'm not able to replicate this here. I think it might be because I'm working with objects. I do in fact need to work with objects though as I want to work with recursion so you generate different pages.

```
import tkinter as tk
import json


class Panel:
    panelType='F'
    panelHome=False
    def __init__(self,parent,payload):
        self.parent = parent
        self.payload= payload
        if(payload["name"]=="home"):
            self.panelHome=True
            self.panelType='G'
        else:
            if(payload["list"]=='G'):
                self.panelType='G'
            elif(payload["list"]=='L'):
                self.panelType='L'
        self.boundaries()
        self.printPage(0)

    def boundaries(self):
        if(self.panelType=='G'):
            print("This is a grid")
        elif(self.panelType=='L'):
            print("This is a list")
    def printPage(self,page):
        print("printing page"+str(page))
        useHeight= window.winfo_reqheight()
        useWidth= window.winfo_reqwidth()
        if(self.panelHome==True):
            tk.Button(self.parent,text="Settings").grid(row=0,column=2,padx=20,pady=20)
        else:
            tk.Button(self.parent,text="Back").grid(row=0,column=0,padx=12,pady=12)
            tk.Button(self.parent,text="Home").grid(row=0,column=1,padx=12,pady=12)
        if(self.panelType=='G'):
            tk.Button(self.parent,text="Left").grid(row=1,column=0,padx=12,pady=12)
            tk.Button(self.parent,text="Right").grid(row=1,column=2,padx=12,pady=12)
            gridFrame= tk.Frame(self.parent).grid(row=1,column=1)
            i=0
            tk.Button(gridFrame,text="middle").grid(row=0,column=0)
#            for eachI in self.payload['objects']:
#                tk.Button(gridFrame,text=eachI['name']).grid(row=0,column=i,padx=12,pady=12)
#                i+=1
            print("grid")


home =  {
    "name":"home",
    "objects":[ 
        {"name":"one","object":"go"} ,
        {"name":"two","object":"go"} ,
        {"name":"three","object":"go"} ,
        {"name":"four","object":"go"}
    ]
}
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("PyPanels")
window.geometry("550x500")
panelTree = Panel(window,home)
window.mainloop()
```

What I want to accomplish is for the "Middle" button and all sub buttons that are placed in the "gridFrame" frame to be in the middle of the "left" and "right" button. It looks like its just showing up on the top left tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `gridFrame` to `None`, so the "middle" button is going in the root window.

Comment: but how do I set the gridFrame to something besides none? in the last IF statement, I'm creating it from tk.Frame(self.parent) so like I was assigning it to the parent frame parent. or should I go about it in a different way?

Comment: @AndrewR: _"but how do I set the gridFrame to something besides none?"_ - you create the widget and call `grid` on the widget in two steps instead of one.

Comment: Dude I feel like an idiot I am SOO sorry. That fixed it and here I am trying to do shortcuts. Thank you so much my friend.